# Angular 2 Reactive Forms - Using ignorable fields

Tags: forms, angular, angular-reactive-forms

Is it possible to add ignorable fields to Angular 2's reactive forms?

To simplify things, look at this Form:

```
this.form = new FormGroup({
    subTasks: new FormArray([]),
});
```

Each subTask will be solved by the user and the solution is saved inside the FormArray.

Now in order to display the text of the different subTasks, I added a `FormControl` called "**text**" to each subTask. But when the user submits the form, I don't want the task text to be sent to the server along with the user input.

I know I could just not use it, or remove it programmatically before submitting, but I was wondering if there is a way to do it clean. Thanks!

Comment: Are You passing form values like :   this.form.getRawValue()

Comment: No, this.form.value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you could utilize is to disable the formfield `text`, which means that the field is not included in the form object, but you can still use it. Sample:

```ts
this.myForm = this.fb.group({
  text: [{value:'text value', disabled: true}],
  somethingElse: ['something else']
});
```

and in template:

```html
<form [formGroup]="myForm">
  <p>{{myForm.get('text').value}}</p>
  <input formControlName="somethingElse">
</form>
```

If you want to inspect the whole form object, disabled fields included, you can use:

```html
this.myForm.getRawValue();
```

Comment: Perfect, that's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.

Comment: Great, glad to hear! :)